# do I need to change the default database prefix?

Tags: database

when do one need to  change the default database prefix OTHER THAN SECURITY REASONS?

Let's not worry about securities,so is there any preformance concerns?

See I have four or more worpdress site on one server(not multiplesites),like:http://www.12reads.cn/,http://www.12reads.cn/wiki/,http://news.12reads.cn/,http://peixun.12reads.cn/.

All of them are using wordpress and sharing a same database prefix.Is there any problems for that when it comes to site preformance?

Comment: Having different prefixes will not increase security; nor will it affect  performance.  The main reason to have different prefixes is for separation.  If they all had the same prefix, they would be interferring with each other.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it is easy to do, best practice is to have all wordpress installs use their own DB. Yes it is mainly for security, but it also simplifies tasks like importing and exporting sites.

If you must have several sites on one DB, then all of them have to have different prefix, and there is no other option, no matter if it is goor or bad for performance.

Comment: no i am not using one DB.It's not multiple sites and all of the site have their own DB.

Comment: You mean each one is in different DB, but the use the same prefix? In that case it is simple there is no impact on performance nor on security what prefix you use.

Comment: serval different databases like site1,site2 and they are on the same server accessing by the same phpmyadmin. Is the diffrent DB?